# Powershell Combine Arrays with get-random

Tags: powershell

Hello Below is my momentary Code..

It takes seven random „meals“ out of an list and then orders them into a weekly list ordert in days.

```
# Food selector for the week!
#random Stuff mixed for every day.

Enum Food
{#Add Food here:
    Tacos
    Pizza
    Quesedias
    Lasagne
    Älplermakkaronen
    Apfelwähe
    Apprikosenwähe
    Rabarberwähe
    Käsekuchen
    Pasta
    Ravioli
    Empanadas
    Hamburger

}
function Food {
    $foodsOfWeek = [Enum]::GetValues([Food]) | Get-Random -Count 7

    foreach ($day in [Enum]::GetValues([DayOfWeek])) {
        ([string]$day).Substring(0, 3) + ': ' + $foodsOfWeek[[DayOfWeek]::$day]
    }

}
```

I am trying to make it so it can be combined with more arrays like this:

```
Enum Food
{#Add Food here:
    Tacos
    Pizza
    Quesedias
    Lasagne
    Älplermakkaronen
    Apfelwähe
    Apprikosenwähe
    Rabarberwähe
    Käsekuchen
    Pasta
    Ravioli
    Empanadas
    Hamburger
}
Enum Food2
{#Add Fish Stuff here:
    Whatever Fish I want^^ :)
}

#and an array for meat(like steak)
.....

#an array for som healthy food!
.....



function Food {
    $foodsOfWeek = [Enum]::GetValues([Food]) | Get-Random -Count 7

    foreach ($day in [Enum]::GetValues([DayOfWeek])) {
        ([string]$day).Substring(0, 3) + ': ' + $foodsOfWeek[[DayOfWeek]::$day]
    }

}
```

So it does combine them and takes RANDOM out of them all but I can set criterias like it must have one at least from every "List".
Perfect would be:
Every week at least  once —> Meat, Fish, Vegetables and then the rest is random from the first list...

I hope you guys can help me :)

Kind regards Alex

Comment: You have a concept, the tools and a programmer should  have a bit phantasy to put it together the right way. Preset `$foodsOfWeek` with the required items `$foodsOfWeek = [Enum]::GetValues([Fish]) | Get-Random -Count 1` then `$foodsOfWeek += [Enum]::GetValues([Meat]) | Get-Random -Count 1` and fill up the rest.

Comment: oooh okay thanks I'll have a loock inti it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Albeit this may not be exactly what you are looking for, you could try the following:

```
{
# Food selector for the week!
#random Stuff mixed for every day.

Enum FastFood
{#Add Food here:
Tacos
Pizza
Quesedias
Lasagne
Älplermakkaronen
Apfelwähe
Apprikosenwähe
Rabarberwähe
Käsekuchen
Pasta
Ravioli
Empanadas
Hamburger

}

Enum Meat
{#Add Food here:
Steak
Chop
Beaf
Lamb
Pork
Chicken
}

function Food {
#either
  $Foods =  [Enum]::GetValues([FastFood]) + [Enum]::GetValues([Meat])
#or
  $Foods =  [Enum]::GetValues([FastFood])
  $Foods += [Enum]::GetValues([Meat])

$foodsOfWeek = $Foods | Get-Random -Count 7

foreach ($day in [Enum]::GetValues([DayOfWeek])) {
    ([string]$day).Substring(0, 3) + ': ' + $foodsOfWeek[[DayOfWeek]::$day]
}
```

The $Foods variable of course is not an Enum type but an object collection, however you can then generate your random 'meal' of the day & have the option to extend the list as additional categories are added. To access a specific entry you can index as follows: $Foods[10]

The current variable contains 19 elements ($Foods.count)

Hope it helps,

Comment: ooh thank you! you just gave me the last kik to get it how i need it! :)
 alltho is there a option to misc the $Foods ?  like randomize $foods?^^

Comment: While this allows you to combine both lists, since the selection from the combined lists is random, it doesn't satisfy the requirement of having at least one item from each list in the final output - it is perfectly possible to randomly get all items from one list or the other.